# How to match two column values in df1 and extract corresponding values in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

Table 1:

| Pos | Samples |
| --- | --- |
| 129 | ERR5678 |
| 460 | ERR7890 |
| 568 | ERR7689 |

Table 2:

| Pos | ERR5678 | ERR7890 | ERR7689 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 129 | 67890 | 76879 | 67894 |
| 460 | 56782 | 123478 | 678390 |
| 568 | 78926 | 890765 | 345678 |

Result Table

| Pos | Samples | Dp_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 129 | ERR5678 | 67890 |
| 460 | ERR7890 | 123478 |
| 568 | ERR7689 | 345678 |

table 1 contains the list of Positions and their corresponding samples and another table contains the Position and Depth values for each sample. Using R, two tables read into data.table then I used: `df1[(df1$Pos%in%df2%pos),]`

It extracted the position. Please someone kindly tell me how to match both Pos and Samples in df2 to get the result table.

Comment: Greetings! For some better answers it helps to provide the dput of your data so people can use a reproducible dataset for their work.

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the second data to 'long' format and do an `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("ERR"), 
       names_to = "Samples", values_to = "Dp_value") %>% 
   inner_join(df1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
    Pos Samples Dp_value
  <int> <chr>      <int>
1   129 ERR5678    67890
2   460 ERR7890   123478
3   568 ERR7689   345678
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Pos = c(129L, 460L, 568L), Samples = c("ERR5678", 
"ERR7890", "ERR7689")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Pos = c(129L, 460L, 568L), ERR5678 = c(67890L, 
56782L, 78926L), ERR7890 = c(76879L, 123478L, 890765L), ERR7689 = c(67894L, 
678390L, 345678L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```